# Aggregation Filter Sort - InternalFilter cannot be cast to class InternalMultiBucketAggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have a query like this with aggregation and filter added. I'm trying to sort the results like this

```
GET stats/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "playerid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "gender_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "gender": "women"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum_of_runs": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "runs"
              }
            },
            "top_runs_by_player": {
              "bucket_sort": {
                "sort": [
                  "sum_of_runs"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm receiving the error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "",
    "phase" : "fetch",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [ ],
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "class_cast_exception",
      "reason" : "class org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.filter.InternalFilter cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.InternalMultiBucketAggregation (org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.filter.InternalFilter and org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.InternalMultiBucketAggregation are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

How do I resolve this issue?